# Sturm Liouville problem $X'' + \lambda X=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

given this sturm liouville problem:

(1) $$X'' + \lambda X=0$$
(2) $$X(0)=X'(1)=0$$

I'm trying to solve it.. This where I get to:

First I solve $X'' + \lambda X=0$ and I get that:
$$X(x) = a\cos \sqrt \lambda x+b\sin \sqrt \lambda x $$

Then from $(2)$ I get that $a=0$ and  $\cos \sqrt \lambda=0$
means that $\sqrt \lambda= \frac {\pi}{2} + n \pi $
And now how do I get what $X_n$ are?
I know that $a=0$ but nothing about $b$

Comment: what about $\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}2\right), \sin\left(\frac{3\pi x}2\right),\cdots?$

Comment: @abel What about them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since equations and boundary conditions are homogeneous, you get a linear subspace of solutions. One can also say that you have 2 conditions for 3 unknown parameters.

So set $b=1$.

Also explore the possibility of negative $λ$.

Comment: Thanks you! for $\lambda <0$ You get the trivial solution.

Comment: sometimes it's also useful to set $b = \frac{1}{||X_n||}$.